# Type of a function pointer to method with lifetime parameters

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a lifetime and some methods:

```rust
struct Ctrl<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

impl<'a> Ctrl<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        *self.x + 1
    }
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        *self.x + 2
    }
}
```

Now I want to store pointers to the methods in a slice, kind of like a look-up table:

```rust
const LIST: &[_] = &[Ctrl::foo, Ctrl::bar];
```

Rust demands to know the slice element type and suggests `for<'r> fn(&'r Ctrl) -> i32`, but this results in an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs:16:48
   |
16 | const LIST: &[for<'r> fn(&'r Ctrl) -> i32] = &[Ctrl::foo, Ctrl::bar];
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'s, 'r> fn(&'r Ctrl<'s>) -> _`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r Ctrl<'_>) -> _`
```

Is there a way to specify the correct type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `foo` is a method of `Ctrl<'x>` for *some specific* lifetime `'x`, and not a method generic over all `Ctrl<'_>`. If you try to make all the lifetimes explicit, you will find that some of them can't be expressed:

```
const LIST: &[for<'a, 'b> fn(&'b Ctrl<'a>) -> i32] = &[Ctrl::<'?>::foo, Ctrl::<'?>::bar)];
//                                          What lifetimes?  ^^^^             ^^^^
```

Since `foo` isn't generic, but is bound to a specific `Ctrl<'_>`, there's no way to express the concept you need. You might try something like `<for<'a> Ctrl<'a>>::foo`, but that's not legal in current Rust.

One way to fix this would be to wrap each method in a closure that can be coerced to a function pointer:

```
const LIST: &[fn(&Ctrl<'_>) -> i32] = &[|this| this.foo(), |this| this.bar()];
```

This might get a little verbose if you have a lot of methods or if the signatures are more complex. Another option is to wrap each method in a free function with the correct signature. You could write a declarative macro to make it easier:

```
/// Wrap `Ctrl::$method` in a free function and return it.
macro_rules! ctrl {
    ($method:ident) => {{
        fn inner(this: &Ctrl<'_>) -> i32 {
            this.$method()
        }
        inner
    }};
}

const LIST: &[fn(&Ctrl<'_>) -> i32] = &[ctrl!(foo), ctrl!(bar)];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your inspiration! So it's also OK to use closure: `const LIST: &[fn(&Ctrl) -> i32] = &[|this| this.foo(), |this| this.bar()];`

Comment: Yeah you could use non-capturing closures as well. Mechanically that's the same as wrapping the method in a free function. (I forgot you could do that TBH) Edited the question to add

Comment: With free functions, you can actually use a much simpler type: `const LIST: &[fn(&Ctrl) -> i32] = ...`, no need to use explicit lifetimes.

Comment: @Adrian Yeah, well, it's the same type, just more explicit ;-) But I recommend not omitting the `<'_>` in `Ctrl<'_>`. Doing so is deprecated because it can cause confusion about lifetime relationships, and I expect it will be an error in some future version of Rust. You can use `#![warn(rust_2018_idioms)]` to be warned about it when you omit struct lifetimes (among other things).